# passing stdout to grep as pattern argument

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I'm pretty sure someone already asked this question but I couldn't manage to find it, anyway, here it is :

let's say we have a file :

```
$cat file
AAA 123
BBB 456
CCC 789
```

And I'd like to do some thing like :

```
printf "BBB\nAAA\n" | grep - file
```

where "-" is the standard output. But grep does not consider it as stdout.

and get

```
BBB 456
AAA 123
```

It should also work with many patterns instead of `echo "BBB"`. Instead of echo I have few pipes and a list as an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a trick which does not fully convince me :

```
grep -f <(printf "BBB\nAAA\n") file
```

returns :

```
AAA 123
BBB 456
```

But why is this as in the `file` order?

I find it not practical because it can be rather long instead of `printf "BBB\nAAA\n"`.

Comment: You should keep all the patterns in a file if it is very long string.

Comment: It's not that long (about 20, is it ?). But is there a way to pipe the pattern to grep instead of piping the "file" ?

Comment: Yes you can do: `egrep 'AAA|BBB' file`

Comment: Didn't understand what exactly is the problem with `grep -f <(printf "BBB\nAAA\n") file` You can replace `printf` with any long command and pipes

Comment: Yes I know, But I'd like to know if there a solution with a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu grep you can do:

```
printf "BBB\nAAA\n" | grep -f - file
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me : `grep: -: No such file or directory` (Mac user)

Comment: I am also a mac user but have installed `gnu grep` using `brew install grep`. Unfortunately default `grep` on mac (BSD `grep`) doesn't support `grep -f -` See this [Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76762/how-to-get-freebsd-grep-to-recognize-option)